# Is the OS (operating system) running when the hardware is running?

Tags: operating-system

I learned two things in class.

When a user mode process is running, the OS is not being executed. So when a user process invokes system calls or page faults, then I guess the system is switched to privileged mode and the OS runs without the user processor running anymore?

Another thing is that when the hardware interrupts, the mode is switched to privileged mode and the OS takes over. Does this also mean that when the hardware is running, the OS is not being executed?

Correct me if I am wrong, and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hardware is running"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your misteak:

> When a user mode process is running, the OS is not being executed.

There is no such thing as a USER MODE PROCESS. Processes change modes all the time. It is impossible for a process to run only in user mode.

The operating system kernel gets invoked either through exceptions triggered by the running process or by interrupts triggered by external events. Otherwise, the operating system kernel is not executing.